# How to avoid developers to commit without mention the issue on commit message on Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

At the company I'm working on we've defined a tiny development process to fit our needs. Before commit, we should mention the issue on the commit comments. This will trigger some internal hooks on our CI, and will make the issue available on our beta environment for testing.

Our project is currently hosted on GitHub, and we have a well configured Jenkins CI Server too. The doubt is: **"how we can force our developers to mention a issue before commit?"**. I was wondering if Git Hooks could help us, but it seems that hooks are local on the developer machine.

Does anyone know something that could help us with this?

Comment: How is the hooks being local a problem? Tell the developers to install them, yell at the ones who don't until they do. I.e., manage.

Comment: Does git have pre-commit hooks?
If so this should be fairly straightforward to prevent check-ins that dont have the proper comments.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ar/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
Server Side "Pre-Recieve" hook.

Comment: @Chris server hooks aren't really an option here since the server is run by github. The only hooks on offer there are ones for notifying of changes to the repository, nothing to reject non-compliant commits from being pushed.

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach needs tweaking.  Git is designed to be best when you commit often.  For example, I often commit minor changes to multiple files as individual commits.  Later changes can be squashed or cherry-picked, rebased, or rearranged.  But forcing every commit to be regarding an issue will just lead to -fewer- commits, which isn't good for your developers.

In addition, code needs a backup, and if you push to a remote server, that's a simple way of having your code in two places, and also "sharing" with others during development.  As long as it's a separate branch, that's a great way of working out problems in code.

As far as I can tell, your problem is with granularity and the concept of the github repository as being the "main" repository.  If you only want to -deploy- for general testing a block of commits that deals with a specific issue, then have a git repo that pulls a copy of the central github repo on -every- commit to master, but only triggers the integration/deploy-to-testing process when there is an issue mentioned in the commit comments.  In that way developers can push intermediate commits as needed, can push development branches as necessary without it having to mean anything special, and only issue-fixing commit blocks will cause deployment/integration.

Comment: I've always thought that "Every commit must be associated with fixing an issue" was a terrible anti-pattern.  It's like insisting that every keystroke a developer makes must be traceable back to a requirement.

Comment: Tchalvak, many thanks for your answer. I agree with you concern about fewer commits, it could be a huge problem at past few months. But, recently, all our developers members was trained and adopted the concept of -many commits- as them culture. Today we have about 180 commit a day, on a team with 4 developers.

This week I've noted that about 20 commits hasn`t issues at their commit comments. This avoid some commits to reach the production environment after Q/A at beta.

Next week more developers will work with us, one outside my country.. How can I grant that they will always write the issue?

Comment: Kristopher, I understand your point of view... We don't have many rules here, this "commit issue" and behavior-driven unit tests are the unique rules here. At least, the developer could do more than one commit at the same issue. With the issue wired to the commit, we can automatically move just approved (tested) issues to the production environment and grant that our continuos delivery present almost zero re-work (we used to have a lot of them few months ago).

Comment: I disagree on multiple points. While committing often is great, that doesn't mean all commits need to be pushed to a shared development branch. Pushing to a fork or a remote branch that's just for a feature is perfectly okay, but when you go to merge that into the main development branch, it should only be exactly one commit per feature, I believe. It's impossible to revert if you've got 20 commits for a feature scattered throughout days of history. 
I also disagree with using source control as a form of backup. If one must push to backup, you push to a side branch then squash before merging.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to force the commit messages to have a specific format (i.e. always have the issue in a specific format) then a pre-receive hook might be your only way.

Answer (score 0):

Our team recently encountered the same issue of worthless commit messages with no reference to the ticket number.

How we handled this was twofold.

1. Communication, expressing this was not the proper approach and not valid.
2. Using GitHub pull requests we refused to merge code into the mainline that did not conform to our specifications which now included a commit message format, developers would rebase their branches to amend commit messages to follow the standard.

We considered forcing developers to install local hooks that used regex to parse messages but decided not to go with this approach as sometimes developers would want to quickly commit (versus stash) and they could rebase later and not have to follow the format locally.